# How to improve EF query performance with 20+ Includes()

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an `Activity` model that pulls in models from 7 or so different types of models. Those models have their relationships too, which the activity feed needs to be able to display the information I want. This means I have roughly 20 includes in my query. I've only been doing this for 8 months or so, and I've read about compiled queries, stored procedures, and how all those includes are probably killing me. I've also read that I could change my code first models to be `virtual` so that it can do lazy loading, but I'm concerned that all those database calls would kill my site if I got a large volume of users.

First the model

```
public class Activity
{
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public int ActivityTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ContributorID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectDocID { get; set; }
    public int? CommentID { get; set; }
    public int? BookID { get; set; }
    public int? BookReviewID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public ProjectDoc ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public BookReview BookReview { get; set; }
    public ActivityType ActivityType { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContributorID")]
    public User Contributor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ActivityLike> ActivityLike { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ActivityComment> ActivityComment { get; set; }
}
```

Now the query

```
 var activity = db.Activities
                .Include(i => i.Contributor.BookStatus)
                .Include(i => i.ActivityType)
                .Include(i => i.ActivityLike.Select(y => y.User))
                .Include(i => i.ActivityComment.Select(y => y.User))
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectFollower)
                .Include(i => i.Project.View)
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectType)
                .Include(i => i.Project.User)
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectTag.Select(v => v.Tag))
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectCategory.Select(v => v.Category))
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectCharacteristic.Select(v => v.Characteristic))
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectDoc.Select(v => v.ProjectDocVote))
                .Include(i => i.Project.ProjectDoc.Select(v => v.User))
                .Include(i => i.Comment.User)
                .Include(i => i.Book.Author)
                .Include(i => i.Book.BookReview.Select(v => v.User))
                .Include(i => i.Book.BookReview.Select(v => v.BookReviewVote))
                .Include(i => i.Book.BookCharacteristic.Select(v => v.Characteristic))
                .Include(i => i.Contributor.Followers)
                .Where(u =>
                    u.Contributor.Followers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FollowerID == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId) != null
                )
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.DateCreated)
                .Skip(offset)
                .Take(results)
                .ToList();
```

This winds up being like 6600 lines of SQL (or whatever it is).

The first time this runs it takes 10-16 seconds. And because I am using `Skip()` and infinite scroll with jquery, every single ajax call takes 10-12 seconds the first time. So if I'm getting 10 results per go and there's 100 results then that's over 100 seconds of wait time, which is awful. Now the next time the user visits that page in a short time period it's very quick.

So how should I improve this query and can you provide specifically how to do so and explain the solution because I've had difficulty understanding compiled queries and what not. The only reason I've been able to get this far is because EF makes it easy... which obviously has a cost.

Please pardon and misused lingo.

Comment: Are you using DbContext?

Comment: I believe so, i.e. 'private NameDBContext db = new NameDBContext();'

Comment: How much time does it take when fired this query in SQL server management studio. Use Query profiler to analyze your query. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to switch to lazy loading, which reduced load time by 70%. I realize this isn't ideal due more database round trips, but if the site grows then I'll worry about it then. Not ideal, but I'm more concerned about performance initially. So in summary I did the following

Added `virtual` to the navigation properties.
Removed almost all the includes on the super weighty queries

Result was a 2.5 second load time instead of 15 second (based on browser timeline not sql profiler).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

1. Make sure your database indexes are tuned properly. Joins without proper indexing can kill your performance, regardless of how you're generating your query SQL. If you're using SQL Server, this is easy to do with the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx). For starters, a general rule is that foreign key columns should be indexed.
2. Consider writing this critical path query in plain old SQL. You've picked up quite a few tricks on Entity Framework in the short time you've been working on it, and I'm sure there is probably a way to optimize what you've done, but the sure fire way to speed this up is to bypass the ORM layer.

Comment: I did all my data modeling with code first, I believe that sets up the indexes, but I have no idea. I'm hosting the site on Windows azure, so I think it's sql azure. generally, I don't know how to do what your suggesting.

Comment: If you're on SQL Azure, you can set up a database copy to run on a local SQL instance and test against the local instance. This will allow you to run the SQL Profiler and analyze the results with the tuning advisor. EF code-first does not set up indexes on foreign keys automatically.

Comment: the database shows that there are foreign keys and indexes that were generated by entity framework?

Comment: My bad: it looks like EF Code first does automatically add indexes for foreign keys.

Answer (score -1):

In my project I created repositories for using EF, so I wrote as follow

```
  public IQueryable<Company> Companies
    {
        get
        {
            return context.Companies.Include("BankAccounts").Include("CompanyContacts").Include("MyClients").Include("MyCompanies").Include("Address");
        }
    }
```

And now I can call every where in my code Companies without include.

```
CompanyRepository comrep = new CompanyRepository();
var companies = comrep.Companies(c=>c.FullName == "Made in Azerbaijan").SingleOrDefault();
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: The includes are still being executed when you call comrep.Companies so this would achieve nothing.